# Avoid scope hitting database if association already loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord, code-reuse, named-scope

I have 2 models like so:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :country
   scope :big, where("population > 1000000")
end
```

Then, in the code I load a country with it's cities, like so:

```
country = Country.include(:cities).find(id)
```

But when I execute:

```
country.cities.big
```

It makes a hit to the db with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM cities where country_id = 1 AND population > 1000000
```

Which works fine, but it's not necessary since the cities where all already loaded by the :include.
Is there a way to tell the scope to not hit the db if the association is already loaded?

I can do it with an association extension, but not for a regular scope. On extensions I do something like:

```
has_many :cities do
   def big
      if loaded?
        detect {|city| city.population > 1000000}
      else
        where("population > 1000000")
      end
   end
end
```

But this would be repeating the scope in 2 places and I want to reuse the scope on the city model.

Answer (score 1):

The scope logic uses methods that work with Arel under the hood, and ruby Enumerables don't know how to use them.  You may be able to refactor your logic to an abstraction that can be translated to use either the Arel or Enumerable methods, but this won't always be possible:

```
def self.build_scope(abstracted)
  where(abstracted.map(&:to_s).join(' '))
end

def self.build_enum(abstracted)
  select{|city| city.send(abstracted[0]).send(*abstracted[1..2]) }
end

def self.abstract_big
  [:population, ">", 10000]
end

scope :big_scope, build_scope(abstract_big)

def self.big_enum
  build_enum abstract_big      
end
```

You could then do:

```
country.cities.big_enum
```

A much better idea would be to only eagerly load according to the scope that you want (if you know it in advance):

```
country = Country.include(:cities).merge(City.big).find(id)
```